# How to update BatteryLevel when value changed in BLE Device

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {

    for c in service.characteristics!{
        print("---Characteristic found with UUID: \(c.uuid) \n")

        let uuid = CBUUID(string: "2A19")//Battery Level

        if c.uuid == uuid{
            peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: c)//Battery Level
        }
    }
}
}
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
/* Battery Level */
if (characteristic.uuid == CBUUID(string: "2A19")) && (characteristic.value != nil){
    let value = characteristic.value
    let valueUint8 = [UInt8](value!)
    print("\(valueUint8)")
    print("\(valueUint8[0])")
    let batteryLevel: Int32 = Int32(bitPattern: UInt32(valueUint8[0]))
    print("\(batteryLevel)")

}
}
```

I want to get the current battery level when it changes, but receive no response even when I set setNotifyValue.

Comment: sor, "setNotifyValue()"

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to read value in the method `func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?)`

With Objective-C you can do it as follows in the delegate method:

```
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:(CBService *)service error:(nullable NSError *)error{
    for (CBCharacteristic *characteristic in service.characteristics) {

        [peripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:characteristic];

        // read battery
        if ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"2A19"]]) {
            [peripheral readValueForCharacteristic:characteristic];//you miss the codes 
        }


    }
```

And in another delegate method:

```
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(nullable NSError *)error{
        if ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"2A19"]]) {
        Byte *batteryBytes=(Byte*)characteristic.value.bytes;
        int battery = bytesToInt(batteryBytes, 0)&0xff;
        NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"battery left:%d",battery]);
    }
}
```

> I used the above method to get the battery info of a BLE device
>   successfully.

Comment: awesome! thx for ur help.  But i used the above method to get the battery level value of a BLE device was't successfully when the BLE device's battery level value changed.

Comment: @AliceTeng You mean that you  just want to red the battery value when it has changed?

Comment: Another thing ,you need to confirm the "2A19" is the correct UUID string of your BLE device, even though it is widely used for battery info. My device is "FF0C".

Comment: !=========== Optional(1) Characteristics of Battery service
---Characteristic found with UUID: 2A19                                                               properties = CBCharacteristicProperties(rawValue: 18)

Comment: ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑ That's my BLE device's battery info